# Matrix Mod. sparse row Operator*(matrix , vector)

Tags: c++, matrix, sparse-matrix

I'm implementing a modified compressed sparse row matrix [[reference]](http://www.iue.tuwien.ac.at/phd/wagner/node83.html), 
but I have a problem with Matrix * vector multiplication, I wrote the function but I don't reach to find the bug !

the class used 2 container (std::vector) for store

- Diagonal element (`aa_[0]` to `aa_[dim]`)
- the non zero value off-diagonal (`aa_[dim+2]` to `aa_[size_of_non_zero]`)
- pointer of the first element in the row (`ja_[0]` to `ja_[dim]` )
- in the previous pointer this rules is used : `ja_[0]=dim+1` ; `ja_[i+1]-ja[i]=` number of element in i-th row
- column index stored in `ja_[ja_[row]]` for `ja_[row]` described above is range is `ja[0]` to `ja[dim+1]` ,so the colum index are in `ja_[dim+2]` to `ja_[size_of_non_zero elment]`

here the minimal code :

```
# include <initializer_list>
# include <vector>
# include <iosfwd>
# include <string>
# include <cstdlib>
# include <cassert>
# include <iomanip>
# include <cmath> for(auto i=0; i< A.dim ; i++)
 {
     //for(auto k=A.ja_.at(i) ; k <= A.ja_.at(i+1)-1 ; k++ )
     auto k=A.ja_.at(i)-1; 
     do 
     {    
          b.at(i) += A.aa_.at(k)* x.at(A.ja_.at(k)-1);
          k++ ; for(auto i=0; i< A.dim ; i++)
 {
     //for(auto k=A.ja_.at(i) ; k <= A.ja_.at(i+1)-1 ; k++ )
     auto k=A.ja_.at(i)-1; 
     do 
     {    
          b.at(i) += A.aa_.at(k)* x.at(A.ja_.at(k)-1);
          k++ ;
     }while (k < A.ja_.at(i+1)-1 ); // ;
 }
 return b;

     }while (k < A.ja_.at(i+1)-1 ); // ;
 }
 return b;

# include <set>
# include <fstream>



  template <typename data_type>
    class MCSRmatrix {
       public:
             using itype = std::size_t ;

    template <typename T>
          friend std::vector<T> operator*(const MCSRmatrix<T>& A, const std::vector<T>& x ) noexcept ;

       public:
     constexpr MCSRmatrix( std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<data_type>> rows);


    private:

         std::vector<data_type> aa_ ;    // vector of value 
         std::vector<itype>     ja_ ;    // pointer vector 

         int dim ; 
    };

    //constructor 
    template <typename T>
    constexpr MCSRmatrix<T>::MCSRmatrix( std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<T>> rows)
    {
          this->dim  = rows.size();
          auto _rows = *(rows.begin());

          aa_.resize(dim+1);
          ja_.resize(dim+1);

          if(dim != _rows.size()) for(auto i=0; i< A.dim ; i++)
 {
     //for(auto k=A.ja_.at(i) ; k <= A.ja_.at(i+1)-1 ; k++ )
     auto k=A.ja_.at(i)-1; 
     do 
     {    
          b.at(i) += A.aa_.at(k)* x.at(A.ja_.at(k)-1);
          k++ ;
     }while (k < A.ja_.at(i+1)-1 ); // ;
 }
 return b;

          {
              throw std::runtime_error("error matrix must be square");
          }

          itype w = 0 ;
          ja_.at(w) = dim+2 ;
          for(auto ii = rows.begin(), i=1; ii != rows.end() ; ++ii, i++)
          {
              for(auto ij = ii->begin(), j=1, elemCount = 0 ; ij != ii->end() ; ++ij, j++ )   
              {
                  if(i==j)
                     aa_[i-1] = *ij ;
                  else if( i != j && *ij != 0 )
                  {   
                     ja_.push_back(j); 
                     aa_.push_back(*ij); 
                     elemCount++ ;
                  }
                  ja_[i] = ja_[i-1] + elemCount;           
              }
          }     
      for(auto& x : aa_ )
          std::cout << x << ' ' ;
      std::cout << std::endl;

      for(auto& x : ja_ )
          std::cout << x << ' ' ;
      std::cout << std::endl;    
    }



    template <typename T>
    std::vector<T> operator*(const MCSRmatrix<T>& A, const std::vector<T>& x ) noexcept 
    {     

         std::vector<T> b(A.dim); 
         for(auto i=0; i < A.dim ; i++ )
             b.at(i) = A.aa_.at(i)* x.at(i) ;   


         for(auto i=0; i< A.dim ; i++)
         {
             for(auto k=A.ja_.at(i) ; k < A.ja_.at(i+1)-1 ; k++ )
             {    
                  b.at(i) += A.aa_.at(k)* x.at(A.ja_.at(k));
             }   
         }
         return b;
    }
```

and finally the main

```
# include "ModCSRmatrix.H"


using namespace std;

int main(){
   std::vector<double> v1={0,1.3,4.2,0.8};
   MCSRmatrix<double> m1  = {{1.01, 0 , 2.34,0}, {0, 4.07, 0,0},{3.12,0,6.08,0},{1.06,0,2.2,9.9} }; 
    std::vector<double> v2 = m1*v1 ;

  for(auto& x : v2)
    cout << x << ' ' ;
  cout << endl;
}
```

but the result is different from the result obtain in octave !

I've correct the code and now compile ! it give me the result :

`0 5.291 25.536 9.68`

but the correct result obtained using octave is :

`9.8280  5.2910  25.5360  17.1600`

the strange thing is that the same code written in Fortran works!

```
MODULE MSR
 IMPLICIT NONE

CONTAINS
     subroutine amuxms (n, x, y, a,ja)
      real*8  x(*), y(*), a(*)
      integer n, ja(*)
      integer i, k
      do 10 i=1, n
        y(i) = a(i)*x(i)
 10     continue
      do 100 i = 1,n

         do 99 k=ja(i), ja(i+1)-1
            y(i) = y(i) + a(k) *x(ja(k))
 99      continue
 100  continue

      return

      end

END MODULE

PROGRAM MSRtest
USE MSR
IMPLICIT NONE
INTEGER :: i
REAL(KIND(0.D0)), DIMENSION(4) :: y, x= (/0.,1.3,4.2,0.8/)

REAL(KIND(0.D0)), DIMENSION(9) :: AA = (/ 1.01, 4.07, 6.08, 9.9, 0., 2.34, 3.12, 1.06, 2.2/) 
INTEGER , DIMENSION(9)         :: JA = (/6, 7, 7, 8, 10, 3, 1, 1, 3/)



WRITE(6,FMT='(4F8.3)') (x(I), I=1,4)    

CALL amuxms(4,x,y,aa,ja)

WRITE(6,FMT='(4F8.3)') (y(I), I=1,4)    

END PROGRAM
```

in the above code the value of `aa` and `ja` is given by the c++ constructor putting this member

```
template <typename T>
inline auto constexpr MCSRmatrix<T>::printMCSR() const noexcept 
{
      for(auto& x : aa_ )
          std::cout << x << ' ' ;
      std::cout << std::endl;

      for(auto& x : ja_ )
          std::cout << x << ' ' ;
      std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

and call it at the end of constructor! now I have added the lines of the member at the end of constructor so if you try the constructor you get exactly the same vector written in the fortran code

thanks I followed your advice @Paul H. and rewrite the operator + as follow:
(I didn't change the ja_ indexing because in my class I have a lot of already more or less un-bugged method )

```
template <typename T>
std::vector<T> operator*(const MCSRmatrix<T>& A, const std::vector<T>& x ) noexcept 
{     

     std::vector<T> b(A.dim); 
     for(auto i=0; i < A.dim ; i++ )
         b.at(i) = A.aa_.at(i)* x.at(i) ;   


     for(auto i=0; i< A.dim ; i++)
     {
         //for(auto k=A.ja_.at(i) ; k <= A.ja_.at(i+1)-1 ; k++ )
         auto k=A.ja_.at(i)-1; 
         do 
         {    
              b.at(i) += A.aa_.at(k)* x.at(A.ja_.at(k)-1);
              k++ ;
         }while (k < A.ja_.at(i+1)-1 ); // ;
     }
     return b;
}
```

as You can see I have subtracts 1 from all `ja_` using as indices :

- `x.at(A.ja_.at(k)-1)` instead of `x.at(A.ja_.at(k))`
- different start of index K `k=A.ja_.at(i)-1`
- and different end of cicle (I've used a do while instead of for)

Answer (score 0):

The debugger is your friend! For future reference, here is a link to a very good blog post on debugging small programs: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).
There are a couple of off by one mistakes in your code. If you create the 4 x 4 matrix used as an example in the reference you linked to, you will see that the `ja_` values you calculate are all off by one. The reason your Fortran version works is because arrays in Fortran are by default indexed starting from 1, not 0. So in `class MCSRmatrix` change

`ja_.at(w) = dim+2;`

to

`ja_.at(w) = dim+1;`

and

`ja_.push_back(j);`

to

`ja_.push_back(j-1);`

Then in your `operator*` method change

`for(auto k=A.ja_.at(i) ; k < A.ja_.at(i+1)-1 ; k++ )`

to

`for(auto k = A.ja_.at(i); k < A.ja_.at(i+1); k++)`

Comment: yes thank i've solved subtracting 1 from all the ja_ using as indices